# Regex 301 using WP-Redirect Plugin

Tags: regex, redirect, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-301

I have been using a `Wordpress redirection plugin` which has the option to use `regex` to create rules. I have no experience with Regex and have tried my best to read around and use regex builders app to solve this myself

basically I need to redirect

`/uk/tag/*`  (* been wildcard IE anything numbers letters dash etc...)
 to

```
/uk/
```

Comment: is the someting befor /uk/tag/*  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex is to replace

this 
    /uk/tag/.*

with
    /uk/

you can check/test example [here](http://regex101.com/r/sN6hL8) . It is a good explanation of the regex